# Passing function rvalue reference, when it takes as parameter by value

Tags: c++

I have a function like this

```
void func(SomeObject obj)
{
    ...
}

int main()
{
    SomeObject obj = GetSomeObject();

    func(std::move(obj));

    return 0    
}
```

My question is, since `func()` takes parameter by value, will the copy constructor be called or the move constructor, even after `std::move()`? Or should I need to change function signature like below?

```
void func(SomeObject&& obj)
{
    ...
}
```

Also what is preferred way ? `func(SomeObject&& obj)` or `func(SomeObject obj)` ? In what situation I should prefer one over the other with std::move()?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If `SomeObject` has a move constructor defined, then calling `func(std::move(obj))` will construct the `obj` parameter using the move constructor.  If there is no move constructor defined, then the `obj` parameter will be constructed using the copy constructor instead.

If there is no copy or move constructor defined, the compile will fail with an error.

If you change the `obj` parameter to be an rvalue reference, no construction will be done at all, the result of `std::move(obj)` will be passed as-is, like any other reference parameter.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Remy. So what is preferred way ? func(SomeObject&& obj) or func(SomeObject& obj) ? In what situation I should prefer one over the other with std::move?

Comment: That is entirely dependent on your particular needs. Do you want to allow callers to pass in a temporary object that is created directly at the call site? If so, then use `SomeObject&&` or `const SomeObject&`.  Do you plan on modifying `obj` and want the caller to use the modifications afterwards? If so, then use `SomeObject&`.  Different kinds of references for different purposes.

Comment: Ah sorry  I messed up a bit, I meant ```func(SomeObject&& obj)``` or ```func(SomeObject obj)``` ? In what situation I should prefer one over the other with ```std::move```? Both will allow to pass temporaries created at callsite, then how to choose one over other ?

Comment: Passing by value always makes a copy.  Passing by reference never makes a copy.  So first, you need to decide whether you want a copy or not.  If not, then you can decide which kind of reference you want to use